# merge sort performance compared to insertion sort

Tags: mergesort, insertion-sort

For any array of length greater than 10, is it safe to say that merge sort performs fewer comparisons among the array's elements than does insertion sort on the same array because the best case for the run time of merge sort is O(N log N) while for insertion sort, its O(N)?

Comment: This is not a java question. Also, insertion sort is O(n^2) worst case. Please edit.

Comment: big O does not include constant, so you're comparing `K1*N*log(K2*N)+K3` and  `K4*N+K5`

Answer (score 0):

My take on this. First off, you are talking about comparisons, but there are swaps as well that matter.

In insertion sort in the worst case (an array sorted in opposite direction) you have to do `n^2 - n` **comparisons and swaps (11^2 - 11 = 121 - 11 = 110 for 11 elements**, for example). But if the array is even partially sorted in needed order (I mean many elements already stay at correct positions or even not far from them), the number of swaps&comparisons may significantly drop. The right position for the element will be found pretty soon and there will be no need for performing as many actions as in case of an array sorted in opposite order. So, as you can see for `arr2`, which is almost sorted, **the number of actions will become linear (in relation to the input size) - 6**.

```js
var arr1 = [11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1];
var arr2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,11,10,9];

function InsertionSort(arr) {
    var arr = arr, compNum = 0, swapNum = 0;
    for(var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var temp = arr[i], j = i - 1;
        while(j >= 0) {
            if(temp < arr[j]) { arr[j + 1] = arr[j]; swapNum++; } else break;
            j--;
            compNum++;
        }
        arr[j + 1] = temp;
    }
    console.log(arr, "Number of comparisons: " + compNum, "Number of swaps: " + swapNum);
}
InsertionSort(arr1); // worst case, 11^2 - 11 = 110 actions
InsertionSort(arr2); // almost sorted array, few actions
```

In merge sort we always do aprox. `n*log n` actions - the properties of the input array don't matter. So, as you can see in both cases **we will get both of our arrays sorted in 39 actions**:

```js
var arr1 = [11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1];
var arr2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,11,10,9];
var actions = 0;
function mergesort(arr, left, right) {
  if(left >= right) return;
  var middle = Math.floor((left + right)/2);
  mergesort(arr, left, middle);
  mergesort(arr, middle + 1, right);
  merge(arr, left, middle, right);
}
function merge(arr, left, middle, right) {
  var l = middle - left + 1, r = right - middle, temp_l = [], temp_r = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < l; i++) temp_l[i] = arr[left + i];
  for(var i = 0; i < r; i++) temp_r[i] = arr[middle + i + 1];
  var i = 0, j = 0, k = left;
  while(i < l && j < r) {
    if(temp_l[i] <= temp_r[j]) {
    arr[k] = temp_l[i]; i++;
    } else {
    arr[k] = temp_r[j]; j++;  
    }
  k++; actions++; 
  }
  while(i < l) { arr[k] = temp_l[i]; i++; k++; actions++;}
  while(j < r) { arr[k] = temp_r[j]; j++; k++; actions++;}
}
mergesort(arr1, 0, arr1.length - 1);
console.log(arr1, "Number of actions: " + actions); // 11*log11 = 39 (aprox.)
actions = 0;
mergesort(arr2, 0, arr2.length - 1);
console.log(arr2, "Number of actions: " + actions); // 11*log11 = 39 (aprox.)
```

So, answering your question:

> For any array of length greater than 10, is it safe to say that merge sort performs fewer comparisons among the array's elements than does insertion sort on the same array

I would say that no, it isn't safe to say so. Merge sort can perform more actions compared to insertion sort in some cases. The size of an array isn't important here. What is important in this particular case of comparing insertion sort vs. merge sort is how far from the sorted state is your array. I hope it helps :)

BTW,  merge sort and insertion sort have been united in a hybrid stable sorting algorithm called [Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) to get the best from both of them. Check it out if interested.